# Why use phonegap camera if Android frequently kills app

Tags: android, cordova, android-camera

I am currently working on a Phonegap Cordova 2.5 app that requires the user to take a picture and upload it to our servers. I am using PhoneGap in order to avoid any Android specific coding (and possibly publish it on iOS some day).

As it turns out, Android frequently (but not always) kills my app while taking a picture and by the time the camera module returns a picture, my base app gets restored from scratch and no callback method gets invoked. Any reference to the newly taken picture is lost, see this post here:

[Taking a picture from the camera fails 20% of the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544992/taking-a-picture-from-the-camera-fails-20-of-the-time)

A common workaround seems to be native Android code. Which leads me to my question: Why should I use Phongap if the first and only Phonegap module I am using (the camera) needs some serious hacking? I am aware this is not even Phonegap's "fault" but rather Android life cycle design, but still: How can I defend this choice of architecture? Has it all been reduced to a reusable front end using HTML, CSS and JS? Should I switch to native Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question: PhoneGap is awesome in many ways, so there are numerous arguments to defend it. Most notably, the whole UI needs to be coded only once and being Javascript and CSS there are many developers who don't need to learn another language. Don't underestimate the value of "easiness", if you need to code a relatively simple app, don't bother to go native. PhoneGap will just do fine.

In my case, the app I wanted to build revolves around taking photos. So I don't use the camera in some rare use cases to spice up the user experience, but it is rather the most important part of the app. In this scenario I guess the recommended approach is to go native. That's what I did in the end.

Another approach would have been using a PhoneGap Plugin called "Foreground Camera". 

PROs: Seamless photo taking in the integration. The user actually takes the picture INSIDE your app.

CONs: By default you lose ALL of the camera's capabilities (zoom, front camera, flash, etc.), so you would need to make a serious coding effort to implement some of those features manually.